# Is it allowed to explicitly ask for upvotes in the body of a post?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, ethics

> ← Vote up if you think this post is helpful.

That's an example. I often see such requests in comments, but not sure if it's suitable in post body.

Comment: Clever ... but I'm not going to up vote this ...

Comment: @rene umm..... why not? It's a totally legit discussion. OP here does NOT mean to ask to upvote this question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard srsly? Oh ...

Comment: I flag those type of comments.  Asking for a vote is a guaranteed way of not receiving one from me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course it is not.  Such content should be edited out as soon as it is noticed.

I think it can be [considered a tagline and removed as noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior):

> If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to
>   reduce noise in the questions and answers.

Even if it is only seen as a comment I think that a flag on that comment for being `too chatty` would be reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

Its *extremely poor form*.

Good answers are high in content, and low in *useless* noise (I sometimes have some *useful* noise in my answers, just to please my audience).

And there's already a place that tells you when and why to upvote

[image]

So... its also redundant.

I'd certainly edit out such requests as noise on sight.